# r8168/r8169 support on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, realtek

I know similar questions have been asked in the forum in the past, but I cannot get the exact answer I need: hence, resorting to a new question.

A month ago, my system with r1869 driver module worked properly without any problems. However, now, it doesn't - no network connectivity on eth0 (wired). I solved this by the normal method of going to the Realtek website and installing their module (r8168). Now the system works normal again.

I am sure I had some or the other change which triggered the behaviour but cannot, for the life of me, remember what was the change.

My question is this - what could have possibly caused the r8169 module to stop working?
Kernel updates?
Any recent Ubuntu patches? (though I do not install any updates as I want stability on a working setup)

PS: Title may be misleading - please suggest a more appropriate one if you do have time.

Comment: Ping for attention (suggestions to improve the qn atleast)
Dont want to start a bounty for silly qns just to attract attention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change any else drivers before it started glitch? r8169 has serious uncompabilities with NVIDIA that I am trying to resolve. Always I change my video driver from Noveau to NVIDIA binary driver 331.89, my r8169 makes internet very slow. As I am child and parents don't allow(once I broke my OS trying to install r8168), I can't install r8168. But that is usually needed to fix problems with Realtek RTL8111/8168 Ethernet Cards...

Comment: No other drivers... However r8168 is working fine and i have no problems. Hence marking this as answered.