# Can't connect with ethernet. System keeps trying to connect then give up

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet

Recently i did a fresh install of version 14.04 on my desktop. Despite of some problems, everything is working fine. The only thing that i can't get to work is my Ethernet connection.

When i try to turn on the connection, or plug the cable, the system keeps trying to connect, only to give up after a few moments. Sometimes (mostly after a reboot) i get the message that is connected, but when i try to open a site on the browser i get an error saying that there is no connection.

I don't know how much that helps, but as an alternative, i'm using a wireless USB dongle and that one works just fine (despite some quirks).

I'll be very thankful if someone can help me.

---

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
*-network               
   descrição: Ethernet interface
   produto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   ID físico: 0
   informações do barramento: pci@0000:03:00.0
   nome lógico: eth0
   versão: 06
   serial: 94:de:80:2f:aa:76
   tamanho: 100Mbit/s
   capacidade: 1Gbit/s
   largura: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuração: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   recursos: irq:73 porta de E/S:d000(tamanho=256) memória:d0004000-d0004fff memória:d0000000-d0003fff
 *-network
   descrição: Interface sem fio
   ID físico: 1
   informações do barramento: usb@8:1
   nome lógico: wlan0
   serial: c4:6e:1f:14:38:9d
   capacidades: ethernet physical wireless
   configuração: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=192.168.0.13 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

(The descriptions are in portuguese.)

---

I tried the method indicated on the ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1992200, referred to by Elder Geek. More specifically i used the step-by-step   on https://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/. While i was finishing the steps, i got the message that it was connected, then i tried to reboot, but my PC hung up on the shutdown splash screen.

After a hard reboot, the problem returned. I used the `lspci -v` comand as indicated on the end of the second link and got this:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 73
I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
Memory at d0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

I suppose the system didn't save the change i made on the drivers. I don't know if it helps, but, when i used the command `mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-`uname -runame -r` (the 8th step on the link), i got this error over and over:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:686 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf line 57: ignoring bad line starting with '“blacklist'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:686 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf line 56: ignoring bad line starting with '“blacklist'
```

---

It's working!

The last error i got was because i left the " on the `echo “blacklist r8169″ >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` command (step 5). And i ended up with two lines with `blacklist r8169`. After correcting that and reusing the `mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-`uname -runame -r` command i rebooted and it seems to work fine, now.

Thanks Elder Geek for your help.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo lshw -class network`

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I added the information to the question.

Comment: It would appear that the driver r8169 does not function properly, and one needs to use r8168 instead. source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1992200

Comment: This may not be version specific. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/547066/r8168-r8169-support-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: @ElderGeek So shall we mark this one as duplicate or you wanna post an answer ?

Comment: FYI, if you are planning on sending the output of a command to English speakers, prefix the command with `LANG=C ` to cause it to revert to English.

Comment: @Serg I'll post an answer in 8 hours or so when I wake up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the 8169 driver listed in your configuration for the wired network connection doesn't function properly and the 8168 is the better choice.

1) Download the appropriate version of the driver for your kernel version from the Realtek download page I used [this page.](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=5&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#RTL8111B/RTL8168B/RTL8111/RTL8168%3Cbr%3ERTL8111C/RTL8111CP/RTL8111D%28L%29%3Cbr%3ERTL8168C/RTL8111DP/RTL8111E%3Cbr%3ERTL8168E/RTL8111F/RTL8411%3Cbr%3ERTL8111G/RTL8111GUS/RTL8411B%28N%29%3Cbr%3ERTL8118AS) and chose the Global link for LINUX driver for kernel 3.x and 2.6.x and 2.4.x

2) Extract the contents using file-roller or via CLI with tar `xfvj r8168-x.xxx.xxx.tar.bz2` using the filename of the .tar.bz2 file you downloaded.

3)Install per manufacturers instructions found in the README thoughtfully included in the tar.bz2 file.

If you need further assistance with this process, you may find [this](https://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/) useful.

Initial Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1992200

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change driver of the Realtek ethernet controller from r8169 to r8168. I used the method on https://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/ (via a link by user Elder Geek).